# Global variable in namespace results in "undefined reference to"

Tags: c++, namespaces, global-variables

I am encountering behavior I cannot explain. 
My problem is simple, I want to create a global variable within a namespace and use it in different modules (cpp-files). I already have read many different posts, but no answer resolved my problem.

test.hpp

```
namespace Test
{
    extern int var1;
    extern bool var2;
}
```

test.cpp

```
#include "test.hpp"
namespace Test
{
    int var1 = 0;
    bool var2 = false;
}
```

test2.cpp

```
#include "test.hpp"

void somefunc(void)
{
    Test::var1 = 1;
}
```

Error while **linking**:

```
test2.cpp: error: undefined reference to 'Test::var1'
```

If there is a better way to do this, please let me know, I am open for that.

Please do not flag this question as duplicate of, I already have read all the posts on Stackoverflow to this topic and they did not resolved it for me.

Comment: How do you compile?

Comment: _sorry typo_ and did you "fix" also some typo that was present in the real code? Copy&paste code that reproduces the error.

Comment: @manni66 The real code is realy complex, I tried to extract the important part, so no typo in the real code.

Comment: `somefunc()` is ill-formed even in C for the past 20 or so years. Return types aren't optional. You'll get less flack about your example if you pay attention to such things. Also, did you really verify this example reproduces the issue?

Comment: You did not compile the extracted code!

Comment: @StoryTeller The example should not recreate the error, normaly it works like that (code is correct, typos possible). That is my problem, I have done it 1000 times but now it does not work. I hope some expert can give me hints, what else could go wrong.

Comment: So you want feedback about code we can't see, based off of code that doesn't have the error? Sorry, but it's a bit much. The only advice you can get is to follow the [mcve] guidelines until you actually get a good example or find the issue yourself.

Comment: @CodingCat How can we diagnose your problem without a [MCVE]? Provide one please, your example in the question is useless.

Comment: @user0042 My problem is, that I cannot produce the error. I hoped, that I can visualize my problem with some code, where the error occures. I know that the code is right, but something else has to be wrong and I have no idea what could be wrong. Maybe some expert can give me some hints like "linker file" or "Include guard" (both already checked).

Comment: @CodingCat Thoroughly check your code for typos (capitalizatiton errors and such). It is the most likely reason that you overlooked such in about 98% of these cases.

Comment: I "guess" it is because your variables are actually defined in test.cpp not test.hpp (they are extern there). Therefore, you need to include test.cpp in test2.cpp.

Comment: The only way to get this error is if you are linking a program with `test2.o` but without `test.o` **or** if the order that the linker sees the object files/libraries includes `test2.o` before `test.o`. Most linkers have an option that allows multiple passes of the object and library files to break this ordering problem.

Comment: With `g++` you use `-Wl,--start-group [object files and library files] -Wl,--end-group` to get this multi-pass behavior.

Answer (score -2):

It looks you have problems with your development tool or editor. Try creating a whole new project and try again. (Do not delete your editor's defualt header files and project links.)